# Write a for loop that prints the Keys of 1 nested dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, nested

1> Create a nested dictionary which contains the subject numbers for the subjects you're doing this year in both the Autumn and Spring semesters. In other words, you should have a dictionary with 2 keys, "Autumn" and "Spring", and the values associated with these keys should themselves be dictionaries where the keys are the subject numbers and the values the names of the subjects.

2> Write a for loop that prints out the numbers of the subjects you did in Autumn.

This is what i have

```
my_subjects = {"Autumn": {37315:"Data", 34567:"Sci"}, "Spring": {23456:"Eng", 45879:"Math"}}

for season, season.subjects in my_subjects.items():
    print("\n Autumn Subject Numbers", season)

    for key in season.subjects:
        print(key)
```

### but receive an error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-208-b1fceae351e6> in <module>()
      5 
      6 
----> 7 for season, season.subjects in my_subjects.items():
      8     print("\n Autumn Subject Numbers", season)
      9 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'subjects'
```

Comment: You want the numbers that identify the classes you took each season? or the number of classes you took each season?

Answer (score 2):

With the `.` operator in `season.subjects` you are trying access the `subjects` attribute of the `season` object, which has no such attribute. You should instead assign the value of the second item in the tuples returned by `my_subjects.items()` to a separate variable:

```
for season, subjects in my_subjects.items():
    if season == 'Autumn':
        print("Autumn Subject Numbers:", ', '.join(map(str, subjects)))
```

This outputs:

```
Autumn Subject Numbers: 37315, 34567
```

Comment: this code returns only the number of subjects, not the subject number attached to it.

Comment: Autumn Subject Numbers: 2

Comment: I see. I thought you meant to output the number of subjects when you said subject numbers. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
my_subjects = {"Autumn": {37315:"Data", 34567:"Sci"}, "Spring": {23456:"Eng", 45879:"Math"}}

for season, data in my_subjects.items():
    print("\n Autumn Subject Numbers", season)

    for key in data:
        print(key)
```

Comment: Autumn Subject Numbers Autumn
37315
34567

 Autumn Subject Numbers Spring
23456
45879

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
new_dict = {}

for k, v in my_subjects.items():
    for x, z in v.items():
        if k not in new_dict:
            new_dict[k] = [x]
        else:
            new_dict[k].append(x)
print(new_dict)
```

> ```
> {'Autumn': [37315, 34567], 'Spring': [23456, 45879]}
> ```